# PhpStorm warning: argument type not assignable to parameter type

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, phpstorm, each

I'm seeing a warning in a JavaScript file in PhpStorm in my project, which I'd like to do something about.  I have a code like this:

```
function someFunction() {
    ...
    var myArray = [1, 2, 3, ...];
    $.each(myArray, function() { someOtherFunction(this); });  //warning on this line
    ....
}

/**
 * @param {Number} value
 */
function someOtherFunction(value) {
    ...
}
```

On the line indicated in the code, PHP gives me this warning:

> Argument type someFunction is not assignable to parameter type Number

I do understand what it means and why this warning is given: PhpStorm has no way of knowing that jQuery redefines `this` context inside the `.each` loop callback.  My question is what can I do to hint such redefinition is happening and what `this` really is in that context?

Answer (score 0):

```
function someFunction() {
    ...
    var myArray = [1, 2, 3, ...];
    $.each(myArray, function(i, val) { someOtherFunction(val); });  //warning on this line
    ....
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/
The jQuery docs here show that the arguments of the callback function are what actually handles the values. The first argument passed is the array index, and the second one passed in the value, which is what you seek.

The thing is `this` will never be just a primitive value. jQuery always wraps it as an object.

Comment: _jQuery always wraps it as an object_  - true, but my code does work as expected.

Comment: @AleksG Oh I'm sure it does, but the problem is that PHPStorm expects a primitive number (or maybe a Number oject), not an object holding a number. Hmm, try this though. This is a total guess, but what happens if you do someOtherFunction(+this);?